# VBA type mismatch when code runs and cell is empty or has no value

Tags: vba, excel

I have the following IF Statement:

```
If Cells(i, 4).NumberFormat <> "0.0%" Or IsEmpty(Cells(i, 4)) Or Cells(i, 4).Value2 = "" Then
    Cells(i, 4).NumberFormat = "0.0%"
    Cells(i, 4).Value = Cells(i, 4).Value / 100
'Else
    'Cells(i, 4).Value = Cells(i, 4).Value
    'Cells(i, 4).Value = Cells(i, 4).Value
End If
```

When I launch the code, it runs for every cell that has data in it but,

if the cell is empty it does not run and gives me an error saying "Type Mismatch"

---

Here is the whole code:

```
Public Sub SortMyData()

Dim i As Integer
Dim N_Values As Integer

N_Values = Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row

For i = 6 To N_Values
    'Cells(i, 3).NumberFormat = "0"

    If Cells(i, 2).NumberFormat <> "0.0%" Then
        Cells(i, 2).NumberFormat = "0.0%"
        Cells(i, 2).Value = Cells(i, 2).Value / 100
    'Else
        'Cells(i, 2).Value = Cells(i, 2).Value
        'Cells(i, 3).Value = Cells(i, 3).Value
    End If

        If (Cells(i, 3).Value) > 1000000 Then
           Cells(i, 3).Value = Cells(i, 3).Value / 1000000 & "Mb"
           Cells(i, 3).HorizontalAlignment = xlRight

            ElseIf (Cells(i, 3).Value) > 1000 Then
                Cells(i, 3).Value = Cells(i, 3).Value / 1000 & "kb"
                Cells(i, 3).HorizontalAlignment = xlRight

            ElseIf Cells(i, 3).Value = Null Or Cells(i, 3).Text = Null Or Cells(i, 3).Value = "" Or Cells(i, 3).Text = "" Then
                Cells(i, 3).Value = 0
                Cells(i, 3).HorizontalAlignment = xlRight
        End If

            If Cells(i, 4).NumberFormat <> "0.0%" Or IsEmpty(Cells(i, 4)) Or Cells(i, 4).Value2 = "" Then
                Cells(i, 4).NumberFormat = "0.0%"
                Cells(i, 4).Value = Cells(i, 4).Value / 100
            'Else
                'Cells(i, 4).Value = Cells(i, 4).Value
                'Cells(i, 4).Value = Cells(i, 4).Value
            End If
Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: There may be hidden symbols in the cell. You should run an `Isnumeric(...)` to check the cell first (empty cells return true). The only point where the error can occour is at the `Cells(i, 4).Value / 100` (at least to my eye)...

Comment: Please specify whenever you can, on which line you get the error, it is very helpful to know where the error is and not to have to guess! ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added some `With` for better readability and tested the values before dividing them :

```
Public Sub SortMyData()
Dim wS As Worksheet
Dim i As Long
Dim N_Values As Long

Set wS = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

N_Values = wS.Cells(wS.Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row


With wS
    For i = 6 To N_Values
        With .Cells(i, 2)
            If .NumberFormat <> "0.0%" Then
                .NumberFormat = "0.0%"
                If .Value2 <> vbNullString And IsNumeric(.Value2) Then .Value = .Value / 100
            Else
            End If
        End With

        With .Cells(i, 3)
            .HorizontalAlignment = xlRight
            Select Case .Value
                Case Is > 1000000
                    .Value = .Value / 1000000 & "Mb"
                Case Is > 1000
                    .Value = .Value / 1000 & "kb"
                Case Is > 1
                    .Value = .Value & "b"
                Case Else
                    .Value = 0
            End Select
'            If (.Value) > 1000000 Then
'               .Value = .Value / 1000000 & "Mb"
'            ElseIf (.Value) > 1000 Then
'                .Value = .Value / 1000 & "kb"
'            ElseIf .Value = Null Or .Text = Null Or .Value = "" Or .Text = "" Then
'                .Value = 0
'            End If
        End With

        With .Cells(i, 4)
            If .NumberFormat <> "0.0%" Then
                .NumberFormat = "0.0%"
                If .Value2 <> vbNullString And IsNumeric(.Value2) Then .Value = .Value / 100
            Else
            End If
        End With

    Next i
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: WOW!... you just re-wrote all my little bit of code and made it much simpler! thank you!.. can i ask why there is only 1 EndIF and not 2 in the With Statements? i am new to VBA and i am egger to learn!

Comment: @RaulGonzales : You are welcome! ;) The number of `End If` is still the same, I just added 2 single single line `If Then` (without `End If` as it is only one line) to test the values before diving! The most extensive reference to improve in VBA : http://www.cpearson.com/Excel/Topic.aspx ;)

Comment: Thanks for that mate as you also helped me last week! i am very new to VBA. also... do you think is worth learning Python in the future as VBA might die soon?

Comment: VBA is supposed to die someday but is pretty easy to take start with. But then sure, learn Javascript, Python, C#, ... ;)